# The string in Pascal error

Tags: string, pascal

This is my program:

```
program str_err;

var st:string;

begin

      st:='ERROR';

      delete(st,2,1);

      writeln(st);

      write(st[5]);

      readln;

end.
```

I run it and it shows that `st='EROR'` and `st[5]='R'`?

I 've already deleted one character from the string and `st[5]` must be `''`, while it is still `R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your compiler uses range-checking, you'll get run-time error trying to read past the string's end. Otherwise you'll just get whatever garbage is in that memory space. No wonder that it's still occupied by the same character that was there before.
st before deleting was 5ERROR, after deleting it's 4ERORR (string length comes first), so R is still there. If delete copied the string instead of shuffling it in place, you'd get random garbage.

Comment: But how can I make the string become 4EROR, for future uses?

Comment: Just assign to st[5] whatever character you want to be there before deleting. But it's pretty meaningless, after deleting it's free memory, the compiler decides what'll be there, you'll never know.

Comment: You should be sure to just use st in the program. The last character of st is st[len(st)]  Use the len() function to find the index of the last character. Some pascal implementations use st[0] for the length, so you could use st[st[0]]. Range checking should be turned on.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I just found it very simple with your help: While i<=length(s) do begin process(s[i]);inc(i);end;